# Is Facebooks API more restrictive than the site?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm just getting started with the Facebook Graph API and I'm getting the impression that the API is more restrictive than the website in what information it will provide me.

Experimenting with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) I seem to be unable to list friends of friends for instance. Is this to be expected? Is the set of information that I can get out via the Facebook Graph API just a subset of the data I can get out via the Facebook web interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just getting started with the Facebook Graph API and I'm getting the impression that the API is more restrictive than the website in what information it will provide me.

Yes, of course it is.

> Experimenting with the Graph API Explorer I seem to be unable to list friends of friends for instance. Is this to be expected?

Naturally. If you could get not only friends of the active user, but friends of friends also – nothing would stop an app from “mapping” the *whole* graph of who’s friends with whom by repeating this step over and over again.

> Is the set of information that I can get out via the Facebook Graph API just a subset of the data I can get out via the Facebook web interface?

Definitively.

Comment: But there are a lot of users that make a lot of their info publicly available. What's the rationale behind not letting us access that info via the API? Doesn't that just lead to screenscraping?

Comment: Well, that’s little bit like asking, “What’s the purpose of bank deposit boxes?” The clerk is the API, and you’ll only be allowed access to your box through a clerk. Which does not mean it rules out bank heists or breakins (scraping) – but there’s additional measures in place to recognize and prevent those …